# Stop div beside expanding div from moving

Tags: html, jquery, css

I've got an issue where when I have one div expanding, the div next to it will move down as well. What I am trying to do is to stop that from happening but not sure where I am going wrong.

My code so far:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".projectTitle:nth-of-type(1)").hover(
    function() {
       $(".project").height(500);
    }, function(){
        $(".project").height(350);
    });
    $(".projectTitle:nth-of-type(2)").hover(
    function() {
       $(".project").height(700);
    }, function(){
        $(".project").height(350);
    });
    $(".projectTitle:nth-of-type(3)").hover(
    function() {
       $(".project").height(900);
    }, function(){
        $(".project").height(350);
    });
    $(".projectTitle:nth-of-type(4)").hover(
    function() {
       $(".project").height(500);
    }, function(){
        $(".project").height(350);
    });
});
```

```css
#model {
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

.project {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: lightgray; /* Changing background color */
    font-weight: bold; /* Making font bold */
    border-radius: 70px; /* Making border radius */
    font-size: 22px; /* Changing font size */
    height: 350px;
    display:inline-block;
   width: 1830px;
   -webkit-transition:height, 1.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: height, 1.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: height, 1.5s linear;
    -o-transition: height, 1.5s linear;
    transition: height, 1.5s linear;
}

.projectTitle {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #009F4D;
    width: 350px;
    left: 90px;
    bottom: -110px;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 10px!important;
    padding: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
}

.projectTitle:nth-of-type(2) {
    position: relative;
    left: 520px;
    bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 20px 5px 40px 5px;
}
.projectTitle:nth-of-type(3) {
    position: inherit;
    left: 950px;
    bottom: 130px; 
}
.projectTitle:nth-of-type(4) {
    position: inherit;
    left: 1380px;
    bottom: 250px; 
}

.arrow1 {
    font-size:80px;
    color: #425563;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 355px;
    display: block;
}

.projectTitle:nth-of-type(2) .project {
    height: 500px;
}
.handoverExpanded {
    height:0px;
    -webkit-transition:height, 1.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: height, 1.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: height, 1.5s linear;
    -o-transition: height, 1.5s linear;
    transition: height, 1.5s linear;
    position: inherit;
    background-color: #001489;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    left: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.handoverExpanded p {
    font-size: 0px;
}


.projectTitle:hover > .handoverExpanded {
  height: 70px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}

.projectTitle:hover > .handoverExpanded p{
    font-size: 15px;
}

.ModelHeader {
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "model">
<div class="project">
    <p class="ModelHeader" style="text-decoration: underline">Project Delivery Model</p>
    <div class = "projectTitle">
        <p>Project Handover</p>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>HSSEQ</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Project Management</p>
        </div>
        <span class ="arrow1">&#8594;</span>
    </div>
    <div class = "projectTitle">
        <p>Project Receipt & Phase Initiation</p>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>HSSEQ</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Project Management</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Engineering</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Project Controls</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="stageGate">
            <p>Stage Gate Review</p>
        </div>
        <span class ="arrow1">&#8594;</span>
    </div>
    <div class = "projectTitle">
        <p>Project Execution</p>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>HSSEQ</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Project Management</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Engineering</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Project Controls</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Construction</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Commissioning</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="stageGate">
            <p>Stage Gate Review</p>
        </div>
        <span class ="arrow1">&#8594;</span>
    </div>
    <div class = "projectTitle">
        <p>Project Close Out</p>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>HSSEQ</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Project Management</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

And a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2wdnLujv/3/

I had thought about making the position absolute but then my animation for when the div is expanding no longer works. So is there a way I can stop the div beside the expanding div from moving down as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have seen it, the children of the grey container do hold RELATIVE positions in the container. These positions change as the height of the parent container changes

Solutions

1. You could make the parent have a maximum possible height to accommodate for the children (not so intuitive if the children be having a minimized state)
2. You could set a single axis for the headings of the expandable items, with one inclination point, they all would not move when another one is being expanded.... (I'd go for this)

The one I'd go for, requires a good refactoring amount to your code, you could make the parents(titles) have a flex parent container, then the overflows be absolute relative to the titles such that each title holds its children below it..

Comment: I will have a look into flex parent containers, thank you for the advice :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7TizprGknbDalbHplROtag ... I'd recommend this. It's one of the best channels for layout, and the teacher is very amazing

Comment: Hey, sorry forgot to tell you that your idea worked like a charm. I created a parent flex container and the projectTitle divs have an absolute position and the expanded content have a relative position and it works perfectly. Thank you for the help!